# loop through sub directories exploding filenames with bash

Tags: bash

I am new to writing bash and I am sure I am doing this the hard way, so if anyone can help me reduce my code or tell me what's wrong that would be awesome.

I am trying to loop through a main directory as well as sub directories finding filenames and explode them so I can pull parts out of the file names.

My directory structure goes like this, this is just an eample. The folders like "0000" will vary

```
/images/0000/somefilename1_this.jpg
/images/1111/somefilename2_this.jpg
/images/2222/somefilename3_this.jpg
/images/3333/somefilename4_this.jpg
```

My script works fine until I get to `FINALIFS='_' read -ra FINALNAME <<< "$FINALSTR";` where I am trying to explode the file name by the underscore and get it in an array. When I `echo ${FINALNAME[0]};` it is empty. On the last `for done` I get a synax error, if I comment out that last `for done` I no longer get the syntax error.

My ultimate goal is to get part of the file names and their current directory into variables so I can do some stuff later.

```
0000 somefilename1
1111 somefilename2
2222 somefilename3
3333 somefilename4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
for d in */ ; do
   for file in "$d"*.jpg ; do
      STR="$file";
      IFS='/' read -ra SPLITNAMES <<< "$STR";
      for i in "${SPLITNAMES[1]}"; do
         FINALSTR="$i";
         FINALIFS='_' read -ra FINALNAME <<< "$FINALSTR";
         echo ${FINALNAME[0]}; <-- this is empty
         for b in "${FINALNAME[0]}"; do

         done <-- I get a syntax error here
      done
      # mkdir /images/$d$(date '+%Y-%m-%d');
      # mv /images/$d$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')_* /images/$d$(date '+%Y-%m-%d');
   done
done
```

Comment: `echo $FILE | cut -d/ -f3- | cut -d_ -f1 | tr '/' ' '`

Comment: In `to get part of the file names` Is there a constant part to omit at the end of each filename. Please update the expected output in that case

Comment: `IFS` is variable that `read` looks for in its environment; `FINALIFS` is not.

Comment: @sjsam no the only constant in each file is the underscore

Comment: @ExplosionPills can you give me some details as how I modify my code to use your example?

Comment: @CesarBielich : If I got you right, you wish to omit the part after the underscore, including the underscore..

Comment: @sjsam no I want whats before the underscore NOT including the underscore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your script with a `find` and then split it using underscore and forward slash using a `read`:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    IFS='_/' read -ra arr <<< "$file"
    echo "${arr[2]} ${arr[3]}"
done < <(find ./images -type f -print0)

0000 somefilename1
1111 somefilename2
2222 somefilename3
3333 somefilename4
```

Comment: is there a way to specify only files that end with `.jpg` and `.html`?

Comment: Yes using `find` you can do: **`while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do IFS='_/' read -ra arr <<< "$file"; echo "${arr[2]} ${arr[3]}"; done < <(find ./images -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.html' \) -print0)`**

Comment: You are the man, thanks so much that did it and reduced the crap out of my code :)

Answer (score 0):

`find` would do the job

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d "$1" ] # Checking if the directory entered as argument1 exists
then
echo " $1 Not a valid directory"
exit 1
fi
filename_processor() # This is a bash function
{
 temp1=${@##*/}
 temp2=${@%/*}
 echo "${temp2##*/} ${temp1%%_*}"
}
export -f filename_processor
find "$1" -type f -name "*.jpg" -name ".html" \
     -exec bash -c 'filename_processor "$1"' _ {} \;
```

**References**

1. find [[ manpage ]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).
2. Shell parameter [[ expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).